# Python: populate multiple lists which have dependencies

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I need to create 4 equally sized lists based on "seed" inputs. The lists are called A, B, C and D. The number of values in list A, and therefore all other lists will depend on the number of times the list A seed value needs to be incremented to reach 1 (i.e. 100%).

E.g. if the seed value in list A is 0.0025 (0.25%) I will need to have 400 values in the list before it reaches 1 (100%). I then need to perform  other calculations to populate the other 3 lists with their 400 values. There as some dependencies between the lists as below:

1. populate list A using the A seed value and stop when the value reaches 1
2. populate list B by performing a calculation on the corresponding list A value and the list B seed value
3. populate list C by performing a calculation on the corresponding list B values
4. populate list D by performing a calculation on the corresponding list B and list C values
5. Find the corresponding list B value where the list D value exceeds a specific value, called X.

By "corresponding" I mean the same position/index in the list. I won't go into the details of the calculations for lists B, C and D but we can assume it is something simple.

I have done first step, but not sure how to proceed from here:

```
A =  map(lambda x: x/10000.0, range(25, 10001, 25))
```

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to provide all calc function to finish this code

```
num = int(1/seed)
list_a = map(calc_a, range(num))
list_b = map(calc_b, list_a)
list_c = map(calc_c, list_b)
list_d = map(calc_d, zip(list_b,list_c))

list_corresponding = [ele_b for ele_b, ele_d in zip(list_b, list_d) if ele_d > x]
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks